# Prevent user from logging in on multiple computers

Tags: php

I need a way to prevent a user from logging in on multiple computers at the same time.

Currently, when the user logs in, I store the userID in a session variable. At the same time I would like to delete all other sessions with the same userID. Is that possible?

**Edit:**
I didn't mention that the solution has to be file based. PHP talks to a web service and isn't permitted direct database access.

**Solution**:
Thanks for the all the comments. Here is the finished code:

```
// When a new session is created
file_put_contents(TEMPDIR."session_".$userid, session_id());

// For each request
if (file_exists(TEMPDIR."session_".$userid) == true) {
    $session_id = file_get_contents(TEMPDIR."session_".$userid);
    if ($session_id != session_id())) { 
        session_destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you notice a "Related" section of this page, with links to the same question asked a dozen times before?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't find a solution among the related questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time a user logs in, you could write `session_id()` to a file named `$user_id.session`. Then each time you call `session_start()` at the top of your script, load the contents of the file and if the id contained in `$user_id.session` does not equal `session_id()` then you would call `session_destroy()` to destroy the old session.

Alternatively you can (and should) write this same information to a Key-Value Store (KVS) such as Redis or Memcached, or, if you really must, to a database.

---

For clarity, I've added the following information from the comments:

> I.e. each time you log in (on a new computer) you write a new `session_id()` to the file, and thus the OLD sessions are expired (if and when they attempt to reload the site) since they no longer match the `session_id()` in the file.

Comment: That will not work because you get a different session id for every computer.

Comment: This will work nice and will be even better if you write it in the database instead of text file, because you will have to read it every time you load a page

Comment: @PiTheNumber excactly - that's the idea - only the last created session will not be destroyed

Comment: Why use a text file? Use a database.

Comment: a) Text files are more ubiquitous than databases - Tom didn't mention he was using a DB so I don't like to assume, b) if I were doing it I would put it into a key value store such as Redis, c) databases do not scale well when every single HTTP request requires an additional query or two, text files however are cached well by the OS, d) many more reasons. However if and when you go on to multi-frontend setup you will need to switch to a KVS or DB or find a way of synchronising the files

Comment: ok, but still... On the first login you store the session id and then you destroy all following sessions. You have to destroy the old session and save the new one.

Comment: You misunderstand me - I've rephrased my first sentence to make it clearer 'When you first start a session' -> 'Each time you start a session', though the meanings are the same. I.e. each time you log in (on a new computer) you write a new `session_id()` to the file, and thus the OLD sessions are expired (if and when they attempt to reload the site) since they no longer match the `session_id()` in the file.

Comment: I'm not sure why I've been down-voted (perhaps because I didn't assume that the OP had a database available), but I've updated the answer to add clarity. I still do not recommend the use of a database for this.

Comment: what's wrong with one additional query getting one row on primary key? are you certainly sure databases are **that** bad?

Comment: They're not **that** bad, I use them frequently for workloads to which they are suited. But for this use-case a database is not a perfect fit - a KVS such as Redis/Memcached/a filesystem would be better. You may use what you want, but don't try and force the idea that databases should be used for everything when simpler solutions exist - there is nothing wrong with using a filesystem for this problem assuming there is just one web-server - it would be faster and more efficient than a DB (lower roundtrip time) - why not benchmark it if you don't believe me?

Comment: Thank you. I think this would be the easiest solution for me. Direct database connectivity is not permitted on my customers server (PHP talks to a web service), so it needs to be file based.

Comment: :) Thanks for confirmation @Tom

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done this before is to save the session id of the last time that user has logged in inside the database. 
Then in my authentication check I have a look to see if the current session ID and the one in the database match - if not then I log them out (i.e. unset the member session).

But IMO this is not the best solution to the problem. I think a better way of doing things is to not allow a 2nd person to log in (so you don't disturb the first person's experience). This also stops the problem when you have 2 genuine people logging in and constantly logging the other person out.

Comment: a better way? what if the first just have their PC rebooted?

Comment: You'd have to set some kind of timeout on it as well, so that if that does happen then the person can still login after a set period of time.

Comment: ever been in the place of such person, unable to log in?

Comment: Can't say I have, but I still think it's a better way of doing things, having to wait 10mins to get back into your account isn't as frustrating as being logged out constantly by another person trying to login.
I'm still not sure if there is a better way of handling login security, which if there is I'd be very happy to discuss it, but at the moment if my choice was to annoy my members by logging them out if someone else logs in their account elsewhere, or setting a timeout on the login session, I'd choose the timeout every time.

Comment: Well, have you ever seen such way implemented anywhere?

Comment: Yes, I've implemented both ways in the past upon clients requests.
I've also seen both methods used elsewhere.
To give a couple of examples, Paypal uses the "auto-logout when someone else logs in as you" method, whereas my bank uses the "don't allow anyone to login if you are already logged in" method.

Comment: well, you can see the weights. a paypal (as well as ICQ, Skype and many other well-known apps) do the first and some obscure bank doing the second.